# Why is my sleeping thread not being interrupted?

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to interrupt a sleeping thread, but it throws `InterruptedException` and doesn't stop. When I put `Thread.interrupt()` to the catch block, it interrupts the thread, but not from the first try.

I have a message, which must be written to file, when the thread is interrupted, but it write this message about 4-5 times. So I understand that thread is not interrupted at once. Why is it so, and what do I have to do?

My code has variable count of threads which changes at run-time. Each thread call method `printAndDelay`, which makes record to file and sleep. But I must have opportunity to stop any thread in any moment from main thread and record reason of stop to the same file.

```
void printAndDelay(String message, int delay)
{
    try {
        writeToLogFile(message, logFileName);
        Thread.sleep(delay);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        writeToLogFile("The reason of cancelling", logFileName);
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}
```

I try to interrupt thread by this code:

```
void stopOrder(String threadName)
{
    Map<Thread, StackTraceElement[]> threads = Thread.getAllStackTraces();

    threads.keySet().stream()
        .filter(k -> k.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(threadName))
        .findFirst()
        .get()
        .interrupt();
}
```

and I see that I can find this thread, but it throws InterruptException but doesn't stop thread. So I tried to stop it by putting `Thread.interrupt()` into the catch block.

Comment: You're catching the interruption, but not doing anything to actually stop what this thread is doing. Calling `interrupt()` merely flags that the thread was interrupted, nothing more.

Comment: @Michael having a thread call `interrupt()` on itself is very common. You do this to preserve the fact of interruption when you can't throw `InterruptedException`. [This](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp05236/index.html) is a good read if you haven't come across it.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't show, this thread is in background, and i try to interrupt it from the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

For the message to be printed 4-5 times, you presumably have some loop which is calling `printAndDelay` multiple times:

```
for (Object obj : someList)
{
    printAndDelay("hello", 1000);
}
```

Rather than dealing with the exception within `printAndDelay`, declare it as thrown in the method signature and deal with it from where the method is called.

```
void printAndDelay(String message, int delay) throws InterruptedException
{
    writeToLogFile(message, logFileName);
    Thread.sleep(delay);
}
```

You would alter your loop like so:

```
try
{
    for (Object obj : someList)
    {
        printAndDelay("hello", 1000);
    }
}
catch (final InterruptedException e)
{
    writeToLogFile("The reason of cancelling", logFileName);
}
```

If `"the reason of cancelling"` is not a constant, you may want to wrap the `InterruptedException` in some other exception type, possibly a custom one, to pass the message upwards.

Comment: No, i haven't any loop calling printAndDelay. Just i can't interrupt this thread, so i put Thread.interrupt() into catch block. It stops thread, but as i noticed, in several times, not at once. May it be so, because i don't use 'final'?

Comment: @СергейУдальцов Post more of your code. Where the thread is created, where `printAndDelay` is called from, and where you are attempting to interrupt it. Edit that information into your question.

Comment: i changed my start post, may be it will helps to understand me

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it like this. Stop the execution of the thread by throwing the InterruptedException.

```
void printAndDelay(String message, int delay)  throws InterruptedException {

try {
    writeToLogFile(message, logFileName);
    Thread.sleep(delay);


} catch (InterruptedException e) {


    writeToLogFile("The reason of cancelling", logFileName);
    // propagate the exception
    throw e;
}
```

}

And in the run method you need to restore the interrupt status.

```
public void run() { 
    try {
         // whatever you want to do
         printAndDelay(.....
     }
     catch (InterruptedException e) { 
         // Restore the interrupted status
          Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
     }
}
```

The reason why I throw the InterruptedException and don't wrap it in another exception is that I want to restore the interrupt of the thread in the run method. You can even restore the interrupt right in the method and then throw some custom exception or a RuntimeException and stop the execution of your thread.